# Using a VPN for a travis deploy script

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm using a corporate install of [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) for [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration). So far triggering a build through a commit and using encrypted values work well.
For deployment however I need to connect to a server that I only can reach via a VPN tunnel (OpenVPN based).
I'm looking for a sample `.travis.yml` file that has a VPN connection. So far my file looks like this:

```
language: java
addons:
  ssh_known_hosts: some.host.in.vpn.org
git:
  depth: 3
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install -qq rpm
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_fancynumber_key -iv $encrypted_fancynumber_iv -in supersecret_rsa.enc -out supersecret_rsa -d
before_deploy:
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  - chmod 600 $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/supersecret_rsa
  - ssh-add $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/supersecret_rsa
deploy:
  provider: script
  skip_cleanup: true
  script: rsync -r --delete-after --quiet $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/build travisdeploy@some.host.in.vpn.org:/opt/coolapp/war
  on:
    branch: master
```

The script runs a maven script (language Java makes travis look for a pom.xml) and rsyncs the build directory onto a server. Works nice without the VPN inbetween.